# Openstreetmap to identify routes

Tags: java, distance, openstreetmap

I want to use openstreetmap to identify routes (breakdown with directions would be nice but distance/time it takes to drive between points would be very useful) between different points in greater London. I think I have to host a tile server or something? I'm not sure exactly what I need to do a list of steps/links will be very useful for me.

I am using Java and I have a linux server and I use mongodb hosted in a linux server to access my data..

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching online for openstreetmap? I found their site and followed links, and although it is admittedly somewhat byzantine, I did find the Engineering Working Group (http://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Engineering_Working_Group), which exists, from what I can tell at a glance, to help novice OSM users.

Comment: @kewpiedoll99 Yes I do I found https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/ but I dont know if it will help me find routes between points.

Comment: I don't know about OSM so I can't provide anything more on your specific question, but I can tell you that you probably will not find a lot of help here on StackOverflow without indicating what you have already tried. It looks like you are asking for someone else to do your work for you. It's possible someone will come to your rescue, but you will probably get more benefit from SO if you show your work, so to speak. Best of luck.

Comment: [Tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) don't help for calculating routes. Instead look at [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) in the OSM wiki.

Comment: If you are already using Java you can use Graphhopper (https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/)

Comment: @scai could you give me any advice on how to get started with routing using OSM? Ive looked at the wiki but cannot find something. I found http://www.routino.org/ but havnt started to play around with it, need to try to install it but I need to download topographical OSM maps but I cannot find them. Thanks

Comment: @RegUser Just install GraphHopper as suggested by sabas.